# How to import javascript file in ionic2 project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic2

After two days of wrestling with this, could someone please explain to me how can I include a javascript file properly into an ionic application?

I have an UMD compatible javascript library (let's call it `foo.js`) that I would like to import in one of my directives. `foo.js` is not available on npm so I cannot install it.

I created a definition file for it `foo.d.ts` but if I import it I get the following error:

```
// file: foo.d.ts
declare module 'foo' { export function bar(): void; };
```

Inside my directive I would like to import it like this:

```
// file: mydir.directive.ts
import * as foo from 'foo';
// ...
ngAfterContentInit() {
    foo.bar();
}
```

> Runtime error: Cannot find module 'foo'

If I simply reference my file in the index.html as a script and use it as a global variable (which should be my last resort) then the typescript compiler shouts that foo is not defined.

I've read the typescript module resolution docs, saw a lot of blog post about how to import third party libraries from node_modules, but I must be missing something trivial here...

My tsconfig file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question, is `foo` in the correct file location to be accessed by just `'foo'`, have you tried using a relative path like `'../somefolder/foo'` ?

Comment: I tried 2 locations since i dont know what the correct location should be... i tried under the node modules folder and also in the same folder as my directive. Should it be somewhere else?

Comment: It's hard to tell without your file structure, but try this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html @zolipapa

Comment: Also if i use a relative path i get a typescript error that my foo.d.ts is not a module

Comment: If the library is UMD compliant, you are declaring it wrong. Anyway, if it is not under src, and if you import it with a non-relative specifier, you probably need to access the underlying Webpack configuration to include it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad How can I access the webpack configuration?

Comment: Not entirely sure, this thread on the ionic2 forms discusses Webpack use https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/howto-webpack/47694